# Get selected keys from filtered list of dicts

Tags: python

This works to return the first 2 dicts matching my criteria from a list of dicts:

```py
[tran for tran in transactions if tran['accountRef']['name'] == name][:2]
```

Gives:

```
[
    {
        "type": "type1",
        "id": "abc",
        "date": "2022-05-10",
        "amount": -175.0
    },
    {
        "type": "type2",
        "id": "def",
        "date": "2022-05-11",
        "amount": 100.0
    }
]
```

But how do I return the filtered list of dicts with only certain keys? E.g., Just `tran['date']` and `tran['id']`?

E.g.,

```
[
    {
        "id": "abc",
        "date": "2022-05-10"
    },
    {
        "id": "def",
        "date": "2022-05-11"
    }
]
```

(This used to work:

```
transactions[ (transactions['accountRef']['name'] == name) ][['date', 'id']][:2]
```

but now it's giving me `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` ... maybe because the data type changed or something.)

For reference, a single item in `transactions` looks like this:

```py
{
    'type': '___',
    'id': '___',
    'accountId': '___',
    'accountRef': 
        {
            'id': '___',
            'name': '___ Chk',
            'type': '___',
            'hiddenFromPlanningAndTrends': False
        },
    'date': '2022-05-10',
    'description': '___ PAYMENT XX0510',
    'category': 
        {
            'id': '___',
            'name': '___',
            'categoryType': '___',
            'parentId': '___',
            'parentName': '___'
        },
    'amount': -175.0,
    'status': '___'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp=[tran for tran in transactions if tran['accountRef']['name'] == name][:2]
[ {key:x[key] for key in ['date','id']} for x in temp ]
```

If you want it as one line, just replace `temp`. To me it seems like you're trying to fit a lot of operations into one line though, for better readability it might be better to break down each step into more digestible pieces

Comment: Your first line gives me `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Ah my bad, the first line should be the same as the first line you provided